# Switching WordPress From Linux server to IIS not working

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

I have website earlier in Linux server. Now we have switched from Linux to Windows Server.

So I have downloaded old files of my Wordpress blog directory & took database backup. I created new database in my windows server & reconfigured `wp-config.php` as per new database connections.

I then uploaded entire directory to new windows server. But It's not working. It just showing 500 Internal Server Error.

What is cause & common reason of this error? & how do I resolve it?

Comment: what does error log say ?

Comment: @Jigar Actually site is uploaded in godaddy server. Is it possible to get error log?

Comment: yes, search in their panel.

Comment: @Jigar It's not linux. It's windows server. I know error log in Linux but no idea about windows